# grails scss variables available via _base.scss

Tags: grails, sass

If I let `application.scss` include my files via `require_tree`, then for any included file, I need to manually include any libraries or partials I need.

Is there any way or a better way to get access to common variables and mixins? I want to create a `_base.scss` that every file doesn't need to manually import to get access to compass's `border-radius`, for example.